# Change Password Validation Rules in Aspnet Boilerplate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I want to set my own Password Validation in ASP.NET Boilerplate for the `UserManager`. I write a custom `PasswordValidator` class which derived from `IPasswordValidator<User>` interface and registered that within the Startup.cs: `services.AddPasswordValidator<PasswordValidator>()`

Now the problem is, that my own Password Validation is active and the default validation of Boilerplate. How can I disable the default password validation?

Answer (score 2):

Create your own PasswordValidator and set it to PasswordValidator property of UserManager in it's constructor. If you create your own PasswordValidator, you can derive from Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordValidator which already makes many checks. Override ValidateAsync method and add your own logic.

[See the issue on github](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/1655)

[See aspnet identity custom password policy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/01/06/implementing-custom-password-policy-using-asp-net-identity/)